# How to specify Terraform remote state backend config via CLI

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In Terraform you can specify a [remote state data source](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data) to access output values from another terraform configuration.

This requires a backend configuration, as follows:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "remote"

  config = {
    organization = "hashicorp"
    workspaces = {
      name = "vpc-prod"
    }
  }
}
```

We do not commit backend configuration in the code, it is specified by CLI parameters. Is it possible to also specify the remote state backend configuration via CLI?

Answer (score 0):

The backend config of a `terraform_remote_state` resource can take variables like any other vanilla terraform block. You can then override them via CLI in the normal way.

```tf
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "remote"

  config = {
    organization = var.org_name
    workspaces = {
      name = var.ws_name
    }
  }
}
```

```bash
terraform apply -var="org_name=hashicorp" -var="ws_name=vpc-prod"
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it can be possible to specify the remote state backend configuration via CLI with **Partial Configuration**.

> You do not need to specify every required argument in the backend
> configuration. Omitting certain arguments may be desirable if some
> arguments are provided automatically by an automation script running
> Terraform. When some or all of the arguments are omitted, we call this
> a partial configuration.
>
> With a partial configuration, the remaining configuration arguments
> must be provided as part of the initialization process.

Please check the **Command-line key/value pairs** of this **[Document](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/configuration)** for how to pass the backend configuration content using CLI

Comment: This document describes how to specify backend configurations via CLI. A remote state backend is a different thing though and to my knowledge cannot be configured with the CLI options you are proposing.